# Logging - How should I class errors, warn, info and so on

Tags: logging, syslog

If I have an application which provides a user to login and view a page and I log to a log file behind the scenes. 
If a user enters the wrong password - should I log this in the log file as ERROR or WARN or something else? 
What is the best method to follow when deciding which level to log at. How does one know I'll log this as a ERROR or WARN?

Answer (score 0):

Try to think like the recipient of the log message. In most cases this is a user or system administrator who runs many services and knows very little about the application, but still has to decide whether the log message requires some action or not.

Assuming you write something like a public web application, then I would argue a failed login should get logged on the `Informational` or `Notice` level. In normal operations it is something that just happens and does not require any action or intervention. On the other hand it should not be a mere `Debug` message (and then discarded in any non-dev setup), because it is still valuable to monitor for too many failed logins in some time interval.